# How to add a wiki to a GitHub repo?

Tags: github

I have a private repo that's part of an organization on GitHub. I don't see the normal link to the repo's wiki that I've seen on many other repos. How do I get to it?

Answer (score 8):

I did a little more digging and figured this out, decided I’d document it for the next person. The GitHub wiki is a setting that’s off by default. From the repo page select Settings on the right side, then in the Features section check Wikis.